# How to re-read JSON file when data changes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an json file that populates some charts. This file is created via various outside data sources and placed in the asset directory. Is there a way to load the json when it changes?

I've tried putting the code to read the json in the init, afterit, or where I am getting the data. It never pulls in the new json file.

I import the data

```
import accessioningAnalyticsDataNC from '../../assets/data/Accessioning-Analytics-NC-Data.json';
```

I have a getData function that read and manipulates the data.

```
getData(location: string) {
    let dataMap = new Map();
    let dayNumCount: number;
    let sampleTypeMap: Map<any, any> = new Map();
    let studyMap: Map<any, any> = new Map();
    let data: any;
    let sampleSet: Set<string>;
    let studySet: Set<string>;
    let typeSet: Set<string>;

    if (location === 'NC') {
        data = accessioningAnalyticsDataNC['day_ordered_data'];
        sampleTypeMap = this.sampleTypeNCMap;
        studyMap = this.studyNCMap;
        sampleSet = this.sampleSetNC;
        studySet = this.studySetNC;
        typeSet = this.typeSetNC;
    } else if (location === 'NJ') {
        data = accessioningAnalyticsDataNJ['day_ordered_data'];
        sampleTypeMap = this.sampleTypeNJMap;
        studyMap = this.studyNJMap;
        sampleSet = this.sampleSetNJ;
        studySet = this.studySetNJ;
        typeSet = this.typeSetNJ;
    }

    for (const day of this.allDays90) {
        if (data[day] !== undefined) {
            for (const i of data[day]) {
                this.dayItem = i;
                dataMap = new Map();

                if (!sampleSet.has(this.dayItem.sample_type)) {
                    sampleSet.add(this.dayItem.sample_type);
                }

                if (!studySet.has(this.dayItem.study)) {
                    studySet.add(this.dayItem.study);
                }

                if (sampleTypeMap.has(this.dayItem.sample_type)) {
                    dataMap = sampleTypeMap.get(this.dayItem.sample_type);
                    dayNumCount = dayNumCount + 1;
                } else {
                    dayNumCount = 1;
                }

                if (dataMap.has(this.dayItem.day_num)) {
                    dayNumCount = dataMap.get(this.dayItem.day_num);
                    dayNumCount = dayNumCount + 1;
                } else {
                    dayNumCount = 1;
                }

                dataMap.set(this.dayItem.day_num, dayNumCount);
                sampleTypeMap.set(this.dayItem.sample_type, dataMap);

                dataMap = new Map();
                if (studyMap.has(this.dayItem.study)) {
                    dataMap = studyMap.get(this.dayItem.study);
                    dayNumCount = dayNumCount + 1;
                } else {
                    dayNumCount = 1;
                }

                if (dataMap.has(this.dayItem.day_num)) {
                    dayNumCount = dataMap.get(this.dayItem.day_num);
                    dayNumCount = dayNumCount + 1;
                } else {
                    dayNumCount = 1;
                }
                dataMap.set(this.dayItem.day_num, dayNumCount);
                studyMap.set(this.dayItem.study, dataMap);
            }
        }
    }

    if (location === 'NC') {
        this.sampleTypeNCMap = sampleTypeMap;
        this.studyNCMap = studyMap;
    } else if (location === 'NJ') {
        this.sampleTypeNJMap = sampleTypeMap;
        this.studyNJMap = studyMap;
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to have it read the new json once it is put in the assets directory.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the service Injectable to get the json data and save the json data back, rather than to import

```
import accessioningAnalyticsDataNC from '../../assets/data/Accessioning-Analytics-NC-Data.json';
```

Subscribe the injectable function to get updated data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ngOnChanges Life cycle hook of angular, so as look out for changes and populate the new json data from the source.

Comment: I have not I will look at that.